# how to have different background color when I scroll top

Tags: html, css, colors, background

Let me explain, on the facebook homepage (login page), when I am in the top 0 of the page and I scroll top then there is a different color background (blue).
I don’t know how to do that to have a different background.

I send you two picture for show you

first picture without scroll :
[image: first picture without scroll]
second picture with scroll :
[image: second picture with scroll]
Is this done through css or javascript?
Thank you

Comment: I don't see the code but jus use two divs with different background color. Also before asking i suggest you to read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the background color is easy and many different methods, I know one method hope can help you.

To change the background color while scrolling, you can use JavaScript and CSS, and also require Event Handler of Javascript.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        document.body.classList.add('change-bg-color');
    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove('change-bg-color');
    }
});
```

and with the CSS :

```css
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
});
```

you can fill the color whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are asking this for safari browser,
this can be easily implemented through [theme-color value for the name attribute of the  element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color).

however, keep in mind that this is more of a side-effect for safari *(because of its inertial scrolling)*, and the real purpose of this `theme-color` is

> to customize the display of the page or of the surrounding user interface

...in other words, to set something like the browser's address bar color.

```html
<meta name="theme-color" content="blue"/>
```

## minimal example

[image: a screenshot of safari showing blue background when scrolled]
(screenshot when scrolled to top)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta name='theme-color' content='blue'/>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        hello world!
    </body>
</html>
```